# How to draw correct headerview border using stylesheets

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets, qheaderview

On the picture represented dialog window with only one widget class `QTableWidget`. My problem is that *bottom* border of the header (red square, `QHeaderView` class) is overlaps with left/right colored borders! What I want, is to make red squares sections view correctly, as green squares.

[image]

Zoomed picture:

[image]

Here is QSS code from Qt Designer which I'm using:

```css
QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal
{
    height: 24px;

    border-style: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #ecedef;
    border-top: 1px solid #161618;
    border-right: 1px solid #b1b1b5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #161618;

    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
 }

/*
QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first,
QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:last
{
    border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
}
*/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView
{
    /* draw the hole hor top & bottom line for the header */
    height: 24px;

    border-top: 1px solid #161618;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #161618;
}

QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first
{
    border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
}

QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:last
{
    border-right-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
}

QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal
{
    /* for each section draw ONLY left & right lines */
    height: 24px;

    border-style: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #ecedef;
    border-right: 1px solid #b1b1b5;

    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
}
```

[image]