# QTableView/QTableWidget grid stylesheet - grid line width

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets, qheaderview

I would like to display a table in Qt with a specific style. I want to draw all grid lines with same color and same width.

Problem is, that it is hard to style `QHeaderView`. All the time, I get a 2px grid width or no grid at all.

I have the following window with one QTableWidget:

[image: QTableWidget]

and associated stylesheet:

```css
QWidget {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fffff8;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #646464;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #fffff8;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

QTableWidget {
    gridline-color: #fffff8;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

QTableWidget QTableCornerButton::section {
    background-color: #646464;
    border: 1px solid #fffff8;
}
```

Are there any tricks to have all grid lines 1px width? I'm using Qt 4.8.5, and I can't upgrade to versions 5.x.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick is **`border-style: none;`** in `QHeaderView::section` after witch `border-left`, `border-right`, `border-top` and `border-bottom` starts working. Correct style for `QHeaderView::section` should be:

```css
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #646464;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    border-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fffff8;
    border-right: 1px solid #fffff8;
}

QHeaderView::section:horizontal
{
    border-top: 1px solid #fffff8;
}

QHeaderView::section:vertical
{
    border-left: 1px solid #fffff8;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you did is you added additional borders for section cells, and the section properties should look like that (although I did not try this solution).

```css
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #646464;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

---

For more information how to style your headers, see:

- ```css
  QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal
  {
      height: 24px;

      border-style: none;

      border-left: 1px solid #ecedef;
      border-top: 1px solid #161618;
      border-right: 1px solid #b1b1b5;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #161618;

      background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
  }

  /*
  QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first,
  QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:last
  {
      border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
  }
  */

  QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView
  {
      /* draw the hole hor top & bottom line for the header */
      height: 24px;

      border-top: 1px solid #161618;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #161618;
  }

  QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:first
  {
      border-left-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
  }

  QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal:last
  {
      border-right-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
  }

  QTableView#tableWidget QHeaderView::section:horizontal
  {
      /* for each section draw ONLY left & right lines */
      height: 24px;

      border-style: none;

      border-left: 1px solid #ecedef;
      border-right: 1px solid #b1b1b5;

      background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #f4f4f6, stop:1 #ceced6);
  }
  ```
- [How to draw correct headerview border using stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024525/howto-draw-correct-css-border-in-header)