# What are the options available within a Qt Stylesheet for a QTableView widget?

Tags: css, qt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have hunted high and low for detailed documentation on the stylesheets for Qt widgets - specifically the QTableView widget. Here were some helpful (although incomplete) resources I found:

1. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html
2. [QTableView/QTableWidget grid stylesheet - grid line width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162387/qtableview-qtablewidget-grid-stylesheet-grid-line-width)
3. [How to set stylesheet for the current item in QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938636/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-the-current-item-in-qtableview)

I am simply trying to get a detailed (complete) list of stylesheet options for the QTableView. Where is this documentation? It seems strange that I have to get bits of information from all over the web to piece together a complete stylesheet.

Here is an example of the stylesheet I'm using right now:

```
QTableView {
    color: black;
    gridline-color: black;
    border-color: rgb(242, 128, 133);
    font: 10px;
}
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: rgb(71, 153, 176);
    color: white;
    height: 35px;
    font: 14px;
}
QTableView::item:focus{
    border: 2px solid rgb(242, 128, 133);
    background-color: rgb(255, 254, 229);
}
QScrollBar:vertical {
    background: rgb(188, 224, 235);
}
 QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: rgb(71, 153, 176);
 }
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    background: rgb(188, 224, 235);
}
 QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background: rgb(71, 153, 176);
 }
```

This is what I still can't accomplish with the stylesheet:

1. I would like to change the color of cells when they are selected in groups.
2. This stylesheet has hidden the "rows" on my table
3. I would like to edit the stylesheet for the rows as well.

Here you can see the cell behavior when selected in group:
[image]
I want the blue cells to match the style of the pink outlined cell.

What are the options for a QTableView widget? I have tried QTableView::rows, QTableView::selection, and many others to no luck.

Comment: It is true that QSS documentation is somehow fragmentary for complex widgets (and some aspects are not documented at all), but, if carefully studied, it usually is enough. That said, some questions replying to yours: 1. do you mean that you want a *specific* color for *group* selection which is different than *single* selection? If that's the case, it's not possible with QSS; 2. What do you mean by "hidden"? 3. Are you asking if you can use different stylesheets for rows and columns? That's not possible: how could you differentiate when to use stylesheet properties for a row or for a column?

Comment: Yes for group selection I just want the grouped cells to match single selection. As you can see in the picture above, the grouped cells are blue, but I want them all to be yellow with the pink border - just like the single selection. By "hidden" I mean the row headers are not there any more. They were numbered - 1, 2, 3, etc. They have disappeared. If any of this is not possible that is fine, I just want to know. I would find it strange that I can't change a simple group selection color though.

Comment: So, you want *all* the selected item to have that "pinky" border just like the current one? Note that "current index" and "selected indexes" are not always the same thing, even from the UX perspective (which is important: the user *must* be able to distinguish between a selected index and the current one)

Comment: Yes thank you, good point. I will omit the pink border from the selected indexes and only keep it on the current index. I have figured out how to change the background color of the group selected cells by using selection-background-color under the QTableView stylesheet entry

Comment: Good, so assuming you solved that, what is it that you're still missing?

Comment: I was hoping to get my row headers back. I am not sure the correct terminology to use to describe this table element. These were the small boxes along each row; they were enumerated - 1, 2, 3, 4, etc for each row in the table. Those headers have disappeared with my current stylesheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important aspect to consider when dealing with QSS (*Qt Style Sheets*) is that when setting *any* property on complex widgets, all other basic properties **must** be set.

The documentation is clear about "common" widgets (like QComboBox or QScrollBar) but not about properties of more problematic widgets like QHeaderView (which is the widget responsible of showing the section *title* of rows or columns).

Most importantly, strictly *related* properties like `width` or `height` (which are *not* supported for all widgets) must ***both*** be set.

If you want to set a specific height for header sections in stylesheets, you *must* set the width too.

```
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: rgb(71, 153, 176);
    color: white;
    height: 35px;
    width: 150px; 
    font: 14px;
}
```

Unfortunately, setting sizes with QSS has two drawbacks:

- the size is fixed and based on the "pixel" size;
- text elision is automatically disabled (at least with QHeaderView and with normal styles);

This brings us to an important aspect: stylesheets **must** be used with care (and the only way to be aware of that is experience and studying of the sources). Setting explicit sizes in stylesheets is almost always discouraged, especially when those sizes deal with text displaying. If you want to set a default dimension for the header, you should use the [`setDefaultSectionSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#defaultSectionSize-prop) instead.

Finally, even if the problem was solved by the OP, I'll add the following just for clarity.
Selection colors for item views can be set in two different ways:

1. Setting the `::item` pseudo-selector color:

   ```
   QTableView::item:selected {
       background-color: rgb(242, 128, 133);
   }
   ```

   The above will set the background of the item and completely override the style painting behavior (depending on the style), including any further "fancy" drawing that is based on the palette. Simply put, it will probably be a *plain* background color.
2. Setting the item view selector and the `selection-background-color` property:

   ```
   QTableView {
       ...
       selection-background-color: rgb(242, 128, 133);
   }
   ```

   The above will set the table `Highlight` palette role, which will then revert to the default style painting, providing any "fancy" drawing used by the style.

Note: styles use palette colors as a *reference*, and sometimes they completely ignore them by using custom (and often pixmap based) painting. As said above, the `selection-background-color` approach still relies a lot on the style, which means that the painting will be partially (or completely) overridden by the style, potentially ignoring or altering the selected color. If the selection color is more important than application/system style consistency, you should use the `::item:selected` selector.